# How to get Application update?

Tags: android, deployment, google-play, versioning

I have developed one android application which is now at Google Play store.

During development I was using my phone to run app. As we know by default app will gets signed with default keystore.

Before deployment I have signed apk with new keystore and also updated version code from 1 to 3 as well as also changed version name from 1.0 to 3.0.

**Note: After changing version code and names I have not ran app to my device.
So my device will have app version 1 and playstore has version 3.**

Question:

1. When I go to my application on playstore, instead of "Install" option its showing "Open" option.(Earlier app was signed with my pc default keystore and now its signed with new keystore, it should show "Install") Why its showing Open button?
2. On change of version code and name it should show "Update" option. but its not.

Can anyone please explain why this happening?

Comment: Android OS might be checking only the package name of the application to find whether the app is installed or not. Since you have your debug version installed in your device, it wont show Install option. Also inorder to get app updates, they might be checking similar keystores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is showing OPEN button because the application with same package name is already installed.
2. It won't show UPDATE button because the installed application is signed with different certificate than Google Play application. Only apps signed with same certificate can be updated.

Comment: Thanks for Perfect answer

Comment: @RohanPatel, if the answer helped, please mark it as *Correct*.